# Installing Byobu on Synology DSM

Tags: synology, byobu

I have a Synology DS412+ running DSM 5.2. I would like to install and use byobu on this machine when I log in via SSH. I went as far as the following:

- install ipkg for this DSM/CPU
- running the following https://gist.github.com/agocs/620cb7819425ff8021a1
- try to run 'byobu' only to get:

> ```
> Aleph> byobu
> BusyBox v1.16.1 (2015-06-29 18:12:44 CST) multi-call binary.
>
> Usage: readlink FILE
>
> Display the value of a symlink
>
> BusyBox v1.16.1 (2015-06-29 18:12:44 CST) multi-call binary.
>
> Usage: dirname FILENAME
>
> Strip non-directory suffix from FILENAME
>
> BusyBox v1.16.1 (2015-06-29 18:12:44 CST) multi-call binary.
>
> Usage: dirname FILENAME
>
> Strip non-directory suffix from FILENAME
> ```

I am not super experienced with Linux, and this flavor with ash for a shell is unfamiliar territory. What should I do next?

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of Synology DiskStations as well, and I haven't been able to get Byobu running on them yet either.

For starters, you'd need to get either GNU Screen or Tmux built and running on the Synology before trying Byobu.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Thank you for responding, Dustin. I will just stick to running it on another machine for the time being then.

Ninja edit: how do I cleanly uninstall Byobu in this situation?